# No matching distribution found for tensorflow" even though I meet the requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, pip

I have seen this question before, but I totally meet all the requirements I can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) (the requirements) I am using python 3.5-3.8 actually 3.6.2, pip 19.0 or higher, running `pip --version` returns pip 20.3.3 and I am using windows 10, 64bit and I installed the microsoft visual C++ 2015-2019 redistributable, I really do not know why running the command returns the mentioned error but running `pip install tensorflow` returns

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: Remove 32-bit Python and install 64-bit Python.

Comment: don't I have 64bit Python?

Comment: You can check with `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: I am retarded and thankful, this is the dumbest error I've encountered so far excpet writing goole for google. Thank you

Comment: It's not the dumbest error, it's quite a popular theme at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Btensorflow%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+find+a+version+that+satisfies+the+requirement+tensorflow+ERROR%3A+No+matching+distribution+found+for+tensorflow